# Azure WASABi Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Autoscaler, key ""

Tags: azure, integration, enterprise, activation, wasabi

Got this error while trying to get [this](http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2012/05/26/autoscaling-azure-with-wasabi-introduction/) Azure Autoscale demo project with WASABi from the Enterprise Library 5.0 Integration Pack for Windows Azure working. Error thrown when all instructions followed correctly is:

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   Autoscaler, key ""
>        at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Typ
>   e serviceType, String key) in
>   c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\M
>   icrosoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 57
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstanceTSe
>   rvice in
>   c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices
>   .ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 90    at
>   PB_WASABi_autoscaler.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\Users\daniel\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\PB-WASABi-autoscaler\PB-WASABi-autoscaler\Progr
>   am.cs:line 13

Windows Azure 1.7 libraries are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tutorial (and other online sources) mostly use Azure 1.6 SDK.

> It works when in the console application there is a reference to
>   WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll file from Azure SDK 1.6. Under Azure
>   SDK 1.7 environment there is this error message: Activation error
>   occured while trying to get instance of type Autoscaler, key "".  In
>   the error details we find: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

Solution:

> A binding redirect in your app.config file will solve the issue:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient"
                          publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0"
                         newVersion="1.7.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Source: [here](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/399750#PostDetailsCell_930994)